# matplot lib get window size of subplot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter

If I have an `AxesSubplot` object, how can I obtain the window size of the plot? I can use `get_xlim()`, but this returns a value in reference to the axis labels. I'd like to get the size of the plot in window terms for Tkinter purposes.

```
fig = getFig() 
w = fig.?
h = fig.?

# will be used in conjunction with Tkinter window values
sw = window.winfo_screenwidth()
sh = window.winfo_screenheight()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you probably want is to use the [Figure](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure) class to handle this. You need to create a figure and then get your AxesSubplot out of it. Something like:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot

fig = pyplot.figure()
axes = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
w = fig.get_figwidth()
h = fig.get_figwidth()
```

[get_figwidth](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.get_figwidth) and [get_figheight](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.get_figheight)